# Avoid recompiling expression tree to reference different target (self) in resulting delegate

Tags: c#, .net

Normal closures are able to efficiently be created referencing a different environment object each time. Like in the following example:

```
Action Test() {
    int x = 10;
    return () => x + 1;
}
```

Each time Test() is invoked it will return a closure bound to a different environment object (Delegate.Target), and of course it is able to do this without compiling a new expression each time.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this for delegates that I create myself by compiling expression trees. The closest I have gotten is to take an explicit "self" parameter before the other parameters, and then call the resulting delegate in a wrapper like in the example which binds the environment object, and forwards it as the first argument to the compiled delegate.

So is there anything like Expression.Parameter that I can use to reference the Target of the delegate? And if so, is there a way to create a new Delegate from an existing one, while changing its Target?

Edit:

Here's some code that I use currently. If I could do what I ask, then I wouldn't have to create the wrapper function in each Create() method in order to efficiently capture the target, and I could therefore replace all Create() methods with a single one taking a single TAction generic arg replacing the Action having T1... generic args.

So at call sites I could do like this:

```
WeakHandler.Create((int x) => Console.WriteLine("result: " + (x + capturedVar)))
```

Instead of this:

```
WeakHandler.Create<int>((int x) => Console.WriteLine("result: " + (x + capturedVar)))
```

Here's the the current implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Capture.iOS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use the methods contained here to create weak event handlers.
    /// 
    /// This is especially useful on iOS where adding a handler function to a class
    /// will create a circular reference, and prevent it from being reclaimed,
    /// if the function references the class itself.
    /// 
    /// These utility functions create wrapper functions which accesses the target (self)
    /// reference through a weak reference, so that the object itself can be reclaimed,
    /// while some of its delegates are still registered event handlers.
    /// 
    /// If the "self" object has been GCed when the handler is invoked then nothing will happen.
    /// </summary>
    public class WeakHandler
    {
        public static Action Create(Action func)
        {
            var d = (Delegate)func;
            if (d.Target == null)
                return func;
            var targetRef = new WeakReference(d.Target);
            var invoker = (Action<object>)GetInvoker(d.GetMethodInfo());
            return () => {
                var target = targetRef.Target;
                if (target != null)
                    invoker(target);
            };
        }

        public static Action<T1> Create<T1>(Action<T1> func)
        {
            var d = (Delegate)func;
            if (d.Target == null)
                return func;
            var targetRef = new WeakReference(d.Target);
            var invoker = (Action<object, T1>)GetInvoker(d.GetMethodInfo());
            return p1 => {
                var target = targetRef.Target;
                if (target != null)
                    invoker(target, p1);
            };
        }

        public static Action<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> func)
        {
            var d = (Delegate)func;
            if (d.Target == null)
                return func;
            var targetRef = new WeakReference(d.Target);
            var invoker = (Action<object, T1, T2>)GetInvoker(d.GetMethodInfo());
            return (p1, p2) => {
                var target = targetRef.Target;
                if (target != null)
                    invoker(target, p1, p2);
            };
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<MethodInfo, Delegate> invokers = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, Delegate>();

        private static Delegate GetInvoker(MethodInfo method)
        {
            Delegate invoker;
            lock (invokers) {
                if (invokers.TryGetValue(method, out invoker))
                    return invoker;
            }

            var targetType = method.DeclaringType;
            if (targetType == null)
                throw new Exception("method.DeclaringType is null");
            var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");

            var inParams = new List<ParameterExpression>();
            var callParams = new List<Expression>();
            inParams.Add(target);
            foreach (var p in method.GetParameters()) {
                var temp = Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name);
                inParams.Add(temp);
                callParams.Add(temp);
            }

            var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(target, targetType), method, callParams);
            var exp = Expression.Lambda(body, inParams);
            invoker = exp.Compile();
            lock (invokers) {
                invokers[method] = invoker;
            }
            return invoker;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2:

I'd like to replace the Create() methods with a single implementation like this, if possible (where I don't have to create a wrapper closure in order to capture the target, because I'm able to bind the target directly to the precompiled Delegate):

```
public static TAction Create<TAction>(TAction func)
{
    var d = (Delegate)(object)func;
    if (d.Target == null)
        return func;
    return (TAction)GetWeakInvoker(d);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more context of what you're trying to achieve with this? (The example you've given doesn't achieve anything particularly useful - whereas if you could give us a concrete example of what you're trying to do, we can hopefully be more helpful.)

Comment: In lambda's, arguments are functions, so you can really do whatever you want. However, on some level, you need to pass the argument somehow. One way might be by making a function that returns a function - the outer function would take the closures and hold them to pass to the inner function, which would have the signature you want to expose as public. The outer function would *not* be an expression tree, while the inner one can be. Or just pass `this` explicitly and be done with it :) C# isn't quite perfectly functional, so it's a bit clunky. It's a one-liner in F#, of course :D

Comment: One thing you have to understand is that functions don't care about `this` - if it's present at all, it's just an argument like all the others. The fact that the C# compiler decides to capture the whole `this` when you access some field / method in `this` is just that - compiler's decision.

Comment: @Jon I'm trying to make wrapper functions which invokes methods through a WeakReference to the target object. And I want to reuse the compiled functions, and not have to recompile for methods with the same signature, just because the target differs.

Comment: Please update the question with an example. It's often much easier to follow an example than a description :)

Comment: @Luaan The action returned in the example can be casted to a Delegate, and it will have a .Target property which will reference an instance of an anonymous struct for which a new instance is crated and attached to the resulting Delegate each time Test() is invoked. And the body of the delegate references this instance, without is being a formal parameter according to its MethodInfo.

Comment: `MethodInfo` is an abstraction. The whole delegate is an abstraction. Delegates in C# can have a `this` reference. In IL, `this` is an argument like any other (the only "special" thing about it is that it comes first). Delegates can have a special convention `HasThis` that say they take that extra argument. C# just hides that argument - in IL, it's still passed explicitly. When you cast a method identifier to a delegate, the `this` argument is captured, and is passed automatically. When you stop using C# (such as with expression trees), you have to do all that manually :)

Comment: In other words, it does exactly the same thing I've told you to do - capture the `this` argument in a wrapper class (`delegate` is a wrapper class for a method handle), and pass it when invoking the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the sample code :)

Don't bother trying to rewrite that with expression trees, it's way too much work.

Instead, just use a code generator (for example T4, which is integrated in Visual Studio) to generate the different `Create` methods and be done with it. This is the way the delegates and the relevant methods are handled in .NET itself as well. This way you'll only write the code once, but you'll have all the necessary overloads.

As for the `GetInvoker` method, you can use `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` instead:

```
var invoker = (Action<T1>)d.Method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T1>), target);
```

Note that you have to do this in the wrapping function, not outside - you don't know the proper `target` at that point, of course.

A full sample for LINQPad:

```
public void Main()
{ 
  x = 52;

  var d = (Action)Test;
  var d2 = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), new UserQuery(), d.Method);

  d();
  d2();
}

int x = 42;

public void Test()
{
  x.Dump();
}
```

This shows how you can change the target of a captured method delegate - the `d()` invocation will show `52`, because I've changed the field value, while `d2()` has a new `UserQuery` as target, so it will print out the default value of `42`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Using CreateDelegate inside the wrapper function appears to make method invocation take approximately 10 times longer, unfortunately. So I guess I will keep GetInvoker, and use code generation to make all needed Create variations.

Comment: Hah, that's quite a difference. I've always used emitted IL (and nowadays, compiled expressions) before, which is a lot cheaper. I guess the expression compiler does a few more optimizations now that it's not just a dirty hack anymore :D